Why does DeviceIoControl in HIDAPI fail with "(0x00000057) The parameter is incorrect" in my Visual Studio project?
I’ve made this project using C++ and HIDAPI to interact with a dualsense controller.
#include <hidapi/hidapi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

hid_device* find_device(unsigned short vendor_id, unsigned short product_id) {
    struct hid_device_info* devices = hid_enumerate(0x0, 0x0);
    hid_device* target_device = nullptr;

    for (struct hid_device_info* cur = devices; cur != nullptr; cur = cur->next) {
        if (cur->vendor_id == vendor_id && cur->product_id == product_id) {
            std::wcout << L"Found device: " << cur->manufacturer_string
                << L" - " << cur->product_string << std::endl;
            target_device = hid_open_path(cur->path);
            break;
        }
    }

    hid_free_enumeration(devices);
    return target_device;
}

bool send_feature_report(hid_device* dev, unsigned char report_id, const std::vector<unsigned char>& data) {
    std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(data.size() + 1);
    buffer[0] = report_id;
    std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), buffer.begin() + 1);
    return hid_send_feature_report(dev, buffer.data(), buffer.size()) >= 0;
}

std::vector<unsigned char> receive_feature_report(hid_device* dev, unsigned char report_id, size_t expected_length) {
    std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(expected_length + 1, 0);
    buffer[0] = report_id;
    if (hid_get_feature_report(dev, buffer.data(), buffer.size()) < 0) {
        return {};
    }
    return std::vector<unsigned char>(buffer.begin() + 1, buffer.end());
}

int nvstatus(hid_device* dev) {
    send_feature_report(dev, 0x80, {3, 3});
    auto response = receive_feature_report(dev, 0x81, 8);
    if (response.size() < 4) return 2;
    unsigned int ret = (response[0] << 24) | (response[1] << 16) | (response[2] << 8) | response[3];
    return (ret == 0x03030201) ? 1 : (ret == 0x03030200) ? 0 : ret;
}

int main() {
    const unsigned short vendor_id = 0x054C;
    const unsigned short product_id = 0x0CE6;

    hid_init();
    hid_device* dev = find_device(vendor_id, product_id);
    if (dev) {
        int status = nvstatus(dev);
        std::cout << "nvstatus: " << status << '\n';
        hid_close(dev);
    }
    hid_exit();
}

hid_get_feature_report fails because DeviceIoControl returns an error. Here’s the relevant snippet from the HIDAPI library:
static int hid_get_report(hid_device *dev, DWORD report_type, unsigned char *data, size_t length)
{
    BOOL res;
    DWORD bytes_returned = 0;

    OVERLAPPED ol;
    memset(&ol, 0, sizeof(ol));

    if (!data || !length) {
        register_string_error(dev, L"Zero buffer/length");
        return -1;
    }

    register_string_error(dev, NULL);

    res = DeviceIoControl(dev->device_handle,
        report_type,
        data, (DWORD) length,
        data, (DWORD) length,
        &bytes_returned, &ol);

    if (!res) {
        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING) {
            /* DeviceIoControl() failed. Return error. */
            register_winapi_error(dev, L"Get Input/Feature Report DeviceIoControl");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    /* Wait here until the write is done. This makes
       hid_get_feature_report() synchronous. */
    res = GetOverlappedResult(dev->device_handle, &ol, &bytes_returned, TRUE/*wait*/);
    if (!res) {
        /* The operation failed. */
        register_winapi_error(dev, L"Get Input/Feature Report GetOverLappedResult");
        return -1;
    }

    /* When numbered reports aren't used,
       bytes_returned seem to include only what is actually received from the device
       (not including the first byte with 0, as an indication "no numbered reports"). */
    if (data[0] == 0x0) {
        bytes_returned++;
    }

    return bytes_returned;
}

When the DeviceIoControl call is made, it fails with the error:
Error Code: 0x00000057 (The parameter is incorrect)
The device is accessible, and I can use hid_open without issues. Other HID operations (like sending reports) work fine.
Reference: deviceiocontrol
EDIT:
I had the same suspicion regarding the OVERLAPPED structure and its hEvent member. To address this, I modified the code to explicitly ensure that the OVERLAPPED structure is initialized with a valid event handle. I should have mentioned that in the original post.
OVERLAPPED ol;
memset(&ol, 0, sizeof(ol));
ol.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

Despite making this change, the issue persists.

ol is invalid. RTM: lpOverlapped must point to a valid OVERLAPPED structure that contains a handle to an event object. Otherwise, the function fails in unpredictable ways.

What for is the first code? It does not call hid_get_report(). A [mre] should be posted.

@3CxEZiVlQ this is wrong. Event can be 0, this is valid case

@3CxEZiVlQ To clarify, the first code represents my current usage of HIDAPI in the application. The receive_feature_report function in the first code internally calls hid_get_feature_report, which in turn calls hid_get_report. So, while the first code doesn't explicitly call hid_get_report, it ultimately uses it through the HIDAPI stack.

@3CxEZiVlQ The code originates from the libusb HIDAPI library. I had the same suspicion regarding the OVERLAPPED structure and its hEvent member. To address this, I modified the code to explicitly ensure that the OVERLAPPED structure is initialized with a valid event handle. I should have mentioned that in the original post.
OVERLAPPED ol;
memset(&ol, 0, sizeof(ol));
ol.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
Despite making this change, the issue persists.

@92half99 data, (DWORD) length, data, (DWORD) length, -- In the call to DeviceIoControl, do you think it's wise to have your input and output buffer be the same?  What if there is some sort of conflict or overwrite when writing output to the input buffer?

amazingly illiterate code, as for a library. of course, it is not necessary to use the event. you can use completion port or apc instead. but it is necessary to use one of these 3 options. without this, the call to GetOverlappedResult is simply incorrect. but this does not affect the result of DeviceIoControl itself

@PaulMcKenzie Thank you for pointing that out. The code is directly from the libusb HIDAPI library, which I assumed to be correct as it's used and maintained. Since I'm still fairly new to programming, I thought the issue was on my end. I'll try modifying it as suggested and report back with the results.

@PaulMcKenzie Sorry for the formatting, I'm not sure how to make code blocks in a comment but this is the changed code. However still get the same error as before.
unsigned char* input_buffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(length);
unsigned char* output_buffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(length);
memcpy(input_buffer, data, length);
memset(output_buffer, 0, length);
output_buffer[0] = data[0];
res = DeviceIoControl(
dev->device_handle,
report_type,
input_buffer, (DWORD)length,
output_buffer, (DWORD)length,
&bytes_returned,
&ol
);

if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING) -- Your code is potentially not reporting the right error code.  When you call GetLastError() you should save/output that value immediately.  Instead,  your code calls register_winapi_error, and I have no idea what that does.  If that function makes a subsequent call to any API (or even standard C or C++) function, then the error code could have been reset to something else.

@PaulMcKenzie Yes you're right. I’ve added DWORD error = GetLastError(); to capture the error immediately. The error code returned is 87, I returned the code to the original implementation and it returned the same error code.
